# Array of slightly different generics

Tags: swift, generics

I have a class that takes a generic type, which must inherit from class `WorldObject`:

```
class WorldObjectsProvider<WorldObjectType: WorldObject>
```

This class will be creating objects of class `WorldObjectType` and return them in one function. Now I would like to create an array of such classes (WorldObjectsProvider), but I want this array to be able to keep many different types of generic classes `WorldObjectsProvider`, for example:

```
class TestObject: WorldObject { }
let providers: [WorldObjectsProvider<WorldObject>] = [WorldObjectsProvider<WorldObject>(), WorldObjectsProvider<TestObject>()]
```

In general I think this might be possible, as all generic types are supposed to inherit from `WorldObject`. This could work by returning all values as references to base class `WorldObject`. But I guess this might be too much for generics. Is there some way to create such an array?

Comment: Generics are invariant in respect to their argument, thus what you need is harder to achieve.

Comment: All generic classes are different types depending on the generic type parameter and Swift generic classes are not covariant, so `Generic<A>` and `Generic<B>` are unrelated even if `B` is a subclass of `A`.

Comment: You might wanna rethink this approach. Maybe create array of protocol types... In general I don't see use of array with completely different types...

Answer (score 1):

Swift generic types are invariant in respect to their generic arguments, which means that `MyGeneric<A>` is incompatible with `MyGeneric<B>`, even if `A: B`.

This being said, if you need to use two different generics, you need a common denominator for the two generics. A type eraser is one of the possible solutions:

```
struct AnyProvider<T: WorldObject> {
    init<U: WorldObject>(_ provider: WorldObjectsProvider<U>) { }
}

let providers: [AnyProvider<WorldObject>] = [AnyProvider(WorldObjectsProvider<WorldObject>()), AnyProvider(WorldObjectsProvider<TestObject>())]
```

This will allow you to use multiple types of generics in the same collections, provided they have a common ground. The downside is the fact that the type eraser will likely have to mimic and forward all public methods of the original type.

For example, if the original provider has a `func someProviderMethod()` method, then `AnyProvider` will also have to declare it:

```
struct AnyProvider<T: WorldObject> {
    private let _someProviderMethod: () -> Void

    init<U: WorldObject>(_ provider: WorldObjectsProvider<U>) {
        _someProviderMethod = provider.someProviderMethod
    }

    func someProviderMethod() {
        _someProviderMethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm ok with down casting all to base type, but how can I later retrieve provider from this container? I tried to create let in that struct and assign it in initializer, but could not do it.

Comment: @DamianDudycz added an example in the updated answer.

Comment: Wow, this is a little complicated, but might work as I need :). Im gonna experiment with this, thank you.

Comment: Turned out that my structure was a little too complicated, and was causing more problems, that I could not resolve in a nice manner with these generic classes. I ended up converting the code, to always return objects by their base class reference, and in providers I have open var that contains WorldObject type. If I want to write a subclass of provider that returns subclass of WorldObjects I can now just override this var, and the rest of my problems are gone, because outside providers subclasses I need to work with base class of WorldObjects anyway.